# Converting C# Code with "SHA512CryptoServiceProvider" to Java

Tags: java, c#

I am trying to convert this C# code:

```
SHA512CryptoServiceProvider sha = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider();
          
byte[] keybyte = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("_AADuKEY101")); ==> RESULT HERE DIFFERS
byte[] newKeyx = new byte[24];
Array.Copy(keybyte, KeyOffSet, newKeyx, 0, newKeyx.Length);
```

This is what I came out so far:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
byte[] keybyte = md.digest("_AADuKEY101".getBytes("UTF-8")); ==> RESULT HERE DIFFERS
byte[] newKeyx = new byte[24];
System.arraycopy(keybyte, KeyOffSet, newKeyx, 0, newKeyx.length);
```

but I get 2 different byte array. What can I try next?

### Edit

The result for `"_AADuKEY101".getBytes("UTF-8")` is the same for both language.

`keybyte` in C#:

[image]

`keybyte` in Java:

[image]

Comment: First, check to see if your `getBytes` and `GetBytes` calls return the same byte array. I don't know if C# and Java use the same endian-ness for encoded bytes, so you might consider checking if a *byte swizzled* byte array hashes to the same value. I'm curious why you do the array copies at the end.

Comment: They are the same sir.

Comment: @Flydog57 Please see my Edit

Comment: Can you share the content of keybyte? Have you checked which one is correct?

Comment: @EdgarDomingues Please see my Edit Sir. The correct one is on C#.

Comment: The content of the byte arrays is the same. C# is printing them unsigned (0 to 255) and java is signed (-128 to 127).

Comment: @EdgarDomingues Thank you for pointing that out. How do I change the value of the JAVA output to be the same as C#. I need this when I use the JAVA's Cipher which in the case of C# is `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider`.  I might not get the same output when I use the this values.

Comment: It is the same. Look at your second byte (index 1). C# shows it as 164, while Java shows it as -92. Both those numbers are represented by the same bit pattern (10100100). Note that the most significant bit (the first one) is 1. If you are consider this as a signed 8-bit number (using 2s complement encoding), then that bit is the "sign bit" and that bit pattern represents -92. As an unsigned number, it's 164. If I remember correctly, Java doesn't have unsigned numeric types, so that's what it shows. But, from a bits point of view, both values are the same